# How to flatten a list inside a map in Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, flatten

How can I go from a **map** of integers to lists of strings such as:

```
<1, ["a", "b"]>,
<2, ["a", "b"]>
```

To a **flattened list** of strings such as:

```
["1-a", "1-b", "2-a", "2-b"]
```

in **Java 8**?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `flatMap` on values as:

```
map.values()
   .stream()
   .flatMap(List::stream)
   .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Or if you were to make use of the map entries, you can use the code as Holger pointed out :

```
map.entries()
   .stream()
   .flatMap(e -> e.getValue().stream().map(s -> e.getKey() + s))
   .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Thanks. I should have asked with the right level of complexity. I actually need to do things with entries before collecting them to a list. Let's say I want to build strings in the format "mapKey-listItem", for example "1-a", so I would end up with [1-a, 1-b, 2-c, 2-d], how could i write that function inside flatMap()? Editing my question accordingly...

Comment: @Rodrigo `map.entries().stream().flatMap(e->e.getValue().stream().map(s->e.getKey()+s))…`. Generally, now that you have some pointers, you should try on your own and come back with questions when struggling with some specific details.

Comment: @Holger Thanks. The combination of both your answers solves my problem. Should I accept this answer as is or wait for Naman to add your bit of code to the answer before accepting it?

Comment: Ok, will hold off until @Naman edits it. I think it'll be easier for folks to see the entire solution in the answer, instead of reading these comments. Thanks both!

Comment: @Rodrigo Updated. Note: The approach remains the same, the implementation has varied as per the change in requirements.

Answer (score 2):

You can just use this:

```
List<String> result = map.entrySet().stream()
        .flatMap(entry -> entry.getValue().stream().map(string -> entry.getKey() + "-" + string))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This iterates over all the entries in the map, joins all the values to their key and collects it to a new List.

The result will be:

```
[1-a, 1-b, 2-a, 2-b]
```