# Convert Map to List using Java 8 Pattern matching

Tags: java, regex, dictionary, java-8, java-stream

I have a requirement to store those employees key matching Address1 to a new `List<EmpData>`, code is given below, I am able to do it by normal iterations.

Can I do it with java8 pattern matching using `collect` and `filter` etc.?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<EmpData> lst1 = new ArrayList<EmpData>();
    List<EmpData> lst2 = new ArrayList<EmpData>();
    EmpData obj1=new EmpData("100", "Name1", "25/05/1979");
    EmpData obj2=new EmpData("101", "Name2", "25/05/1975");
    EmpData obj3=new EmpData("103", "Name3", "25/05/1976");
    lst1.add(obj1);
    lst1.add(obj2);
    lst2.add(obj3);

    HashMap<String, List<EmpData>> map = new HashMap<>();

    map.put("Address1Emp1", lst1);
    map.put("Address2Emp2", lst2);

    List<EmpData> listEmp = new ArrayList<>();
    //Need to store those employees key matching Address1 to a List<EmpData>

}
```

Comment: java8 has no feature named pattern matching, maybe you mean java.util.stream?

Comment: there are type check problem in your code, map's value type is `List<EmpData>`,  but what you put into the map is `EmpData`.

Comment: Yes @jizhilong , using stream.

Comment: @Vinod.T.V please provide a compilant example

Comment: the code wouldn't compile for the line `map.put("Address1Emp1", new EmpData("100","Name1","25/05/1979")` if its type is `Map<String, List<EmpData>> map`

Comment: @Naman i have corrected the code sample, Sorry.

Comment: @jizhilong corrected thanks..

Comment: Would be helpful, if you can also specific the expected output

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm guessing you meant streams from java-8 and the requirement, that the key must match `"Address1Emp.*"` regex.

You can use the following code:

```
map.entrySet().stream() // create a stream of entries
    .filter(e -> e.getKey().matches("Address1Emp.*")) // leave only those entries, whose keys start with "Address1"
    .map(Map.Entry::getValue) // get values only
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Edit after you have added the inner lists:

```
map.entrySet().stream() // create a stream of entries
    .filter(e -> e.getKey().matches("Address1Emp.*")) // leave only those entries, whose keys start with "Address1"
    .flatMap(e -> e.getValue().stream()) // get values only
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: This regex does not work for all cases. You should check for `Address1Emp.*` since you also include entries like `Address11EmpX`.

Comment: @jdickel although I'm not 100% sure that's what OP wants, you're most probably right. Thank you very much!

Comment: This will give List<List<EmpData>> i need to combine all the map values to a single list List<EmpData>, is that possible by altering your sugestion @Andronicus.

Comment: @Vinod.T.V how does that produce a nested `List`? You're putting `EmpData` as a value. If you're saying, that the map has `List<EmpData>` as value type, then you example is not consistent (not mentioning compilant)

Comment: @vinod This gives you enough to answer your original question. You should try flattening your list on your own and asking a separate question if you can't solve it. That helps keep questions focused and more useful to others. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/55520058/227299

Comment: @Vinod.T.V added the new solution

Answer (score 2):

Depending on which pattern you need you can use `startsWith`

```
List<EmpData> listEmp = map.entrySet().stream()
    .filter(e -> e.getKey().startsWith("Address1"))
    .map(Entry::getValue)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

or with `contains`:

```
List<EmpData> listEmp = map.entrySet().stream()
    .filter(e -> e.getKey().contains("Address1"))
    .map(Entry::getValue)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Thanks @htmoia finally i need to combine all the map values to single list , am facing challenge here.